# How to properly use "extends"?

Tags: java, inheritance, extends

i am learning inheritance in my computer science class.
i am confused as too why my code is not working.
this is the code the professor has provided as with:

```
public class Store{

public final double SALES_TAX_RATE = 0.05;
private String name;

 public Store(String name){
  setName(name);
   }
   public String getName(){
  return name;
  }
   public void setName(String name){
  this.name = name;
   }

   public String toString(){
     return "Name: "+ name;
   }
   }
```

The assignment asks us to create web store has the following additional attributes: an Internet address and the programming language in which the website was written. Code the constructor and the toString method of the new class.

this is exactly what i have done however my code is does not work:

```
public class WebStore extends Store
{

 String Link;
 String Lang;

 public WebStore(String Link, String Lang)
 {
 this.Link = Link;
  this.Lang= Lang;
   }

  public void setLink( String Address )
     {
  Link = Address;  
     } 

  public String getLink()
     {
  return Link;
     } 

 public void setLang( String Language )
     {
  Lang = Language;  
     } 
public String getLang()
     {
  return Lang;
     }    
}
```

this is the error im getting:
WebStore.java:9: error: constructor Store in class Store cannot be applied to given types;
{
^
  required: String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

why am i getting this error, my code looks how it is supposed too? im sorry if this si a silly question but i am brand new to java

Comment: As a side note, the Java convention is for local variables and instance fields to start with a lowercase letter so your e.g. `Link` and `Lang` should be `link` and `lang`. Only class names are in camelcase starting with an uppercase letter.

Comment: What happened with your indentation? Presumably it's not supposed to look like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a pretty simple fix. You have to include a `super()` call in your `WebStore` class. I recommend you change your `WebStore` constructor to something like this:

```
public WebStore(String name, String Link, String Lang) {
    super(name);
    this.Link = Link;
    this.Lang= Lang;
}
```

This has to be done in Java because if you extend a class that has a constructor, you have to call `super()` to it with the required arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Your `WebStore` must have a name. So when you construct it, you must pass a name along:  `public WebStore(String Link, String Lang, String name)`.

You can then use your `name` parameter to call the constructor of your parent class: `super(name);`. Note that this must be the first statement of your constructor.

Imagine extending as building a bigger building: Your `Store` represents the foundations, and `WebStore` is a full house. By calling `super(...);`, you ensure the 'skeleton' of your object has been built.

In the end, you'll have:

```
public WebStore(String Link, String Lang, String name)
{
    super(name); // construct the skeleton with this parameter!
    this.Link = Link;
    this.Lang= Lang;
}
```

On a side note, you should consider following the Java conventional notations: variables names should start with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 1):

As you extend Store, it needs to call the Store constructor, which in this case needs to be provided with the store name.

In java, you can call the super class using super(),

```
public WebStore(String name, String Link, String Lang)
{
  super(name);
  this.Link = Link;
  this.Lang= Lang;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In Java a constructor always calls its parent's constructor.
The argument-less constructor is often called as "default constructor".

Your `Store` class has only one constructor, and it has an agrument: `name`.
Thus your `WebStore` constructor should have a call to its parent's constructor, supplying value for `name`. Something like this:

```
public WebStore(String Link, String Lang)
{
  super("name");
  this.Link = Link;
  this.Lang= Lang;
}
```

Comment: Just add a `name` parameter and `super()` that instead of providing a default value.